# SQL query for finding records where count > 1

Tags: sql, count, group-by, having

I have a table named `PAYMENT`. Within this table I have a user ID, an account number, a ZIP code and a date. I would like to find all records for all users that have more than one payment per day with the same account number.

**UPDATE:** Additionally, there should be a filter than only counts the records whose ZIP code is different.

This is how the table looks like:

```
| user_id | account_no | zip   |      date |
|       1 |        123 | 55555 | 12-DEC-09 | 
|       1 |        123 | 66666 | 12-DEC-09 |
|       1 |        123 | 55555 | 13-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        456 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        789 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
|       2 |        789 | 77777 | 14-DEC-09 |
```

The result should look similar to this:

```
| user_id | count |
|       1 |     2 |
```

How would you express this in a SQL query? I was thinking self join but for some reason my count is wrong.

Answer (score 474, accepted):

Use the [HAVING](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause and GROUP By the fields that make the row unique

The below will find

> all users that have more than one payment per day with the same account number

```
SELECT 
 user_id,
 COUNT(*) count
FROM 
 PAYMENT
GROUP BY
 account,
 user_id,
 date
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

**Update**
If you want to only include those that have a distinct ZIP you can get a distinct set first and then perform you HAVING/GROUP BY

```
 SELECT 
    user_id,
    account_no, 
    date,
    COUNT(*)
 FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
            user_id,
            account_no, 
            zip, 
            date
         FROM
            payment 
    ) payment
 GROUP BY
    user_id,
    account_no,
    date
 HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Comment: Notice in his results `2` has a count of `4` - You will want to discard the `Account_no` grouping I think.

Comment: No wait I think the original was right "all users that have more than one payment per day with the same account number."

Comment: it says that but his results show otherwise.  Maybe have both versions with a note.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I think that should do it. If I now wanted to add another filter that checks if the billing ZIP code (same table, different column) is different for the same date how would I modify this query?

Comment: I can't resolve the sample output. If we drop the Account, we'd get three rows. If we drop both date and account we'd get two rows 1,3 and 2,4. So I'm going to go ahead and trust the words over the output

Comment: @Benjamin. Add Zip to the group by clause

Comment: @Conrad Fix: I actually only want to count if the ZIP code is different. If I add it to the group by it would give me a count of 2 if there are two records with the same ZIP code.

Comment: @Benjamin can you update your question with the sample data and the output you want

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Updated my question.

Answer (score 66):

Try this query:

```
SELECT column_name
  FROM table_name
 GROUP BY column_name
HAVING COUNT(column_name) = 1;
```

Comment: neat, but this doesn't answer the question

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't recommend the `HAVING` keyword for newbies, it is [essentially for legacy purposes](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/HAVING-A-Blunderful-Time.html).

I am not clear on what is the key for this table (is it [fully normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), I wonder?), consequently I find it difficult to follow your specification:

> I would like to find all records for all users that have more than one
>   payment per day with the same account number... Additionally, there
>   should be a filter than only counts the records whose ZIP code is
>   different.

So I've taken a literal interpretation.

The following is more verbose but could be easier to understand and therefore maintain (I've used a [CTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_table_expressions) for the table `PAYMENT_TALLIES` but it could be a [`VIEW`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/View_%28database%29):

```
WITH PAYMENT_TALLIES (user_id, zip, tally)
     AS
     (
      SELECT user_id, zip, COUNT(*) AS tally
        FROM PAYMENT
       GROUP 
          BY user_id, zip
     )
SELECT DISTINCT *
  FROM PAYMENT AS P
 WHERE EXISTS (
               SELECT * 
                 FROM PAYMENT_TALLIES AS PT
                WHERE P.user_id = PT.user_id
                      AND PT.tally > 1
              );
```

Comment: A CTE/subquery approach is definitely worth using when readaility/maintainability is the main concern. I disagree, though, that `HAVING` is 'legacy' - it is still widely used 10 years on, and is a very useful shorthand to avoid the need for the verbosity in your example.

Comment: HAVING seems more readable to me, WHERE EXISTS might be faster...

Answer (score 5):

```
create table payment(
    user_id int(11),
    account int(11) not null,
    zip int(11) not null,
    dt date not null
);

insert into payment values
(1,123,55555,'2009-12-12'),
(1,123,66666,'2009-12-12'),
(1,123,77777,'2009-12-13'),
(2,456,77777,'2009-12-14'),
(2,456,77777,'2009-12-14'),
(2,789,77777,'2009-12-14'),
(2,789,77777,'2009-12-14');

select foo.user_id, foo.cnt from
(select user_id,count(account) as cnt, dt from payment group by account, dt) foo
where foo.cnt > 1;
```