# How to select rows where that record has multiple entries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My database has a cost table for items. Items can have more than one cost record.

I want to grab only the items that have multiple cost records.

The UPC field is F01, and the table is called COST_TAB. I only want to grab items where there are multiple entries based on the F01 field.

I'm struggling with how to write this query.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151401/sql-query-for-finding-records-where-count-1. That should help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
select F01
from COST_TAB
group by F01
having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use group by

```
select f01
from cost_tab
group by f01
having count(f01) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from COST_TAB
Where COST_TAB.UPC in (select COST_TAB.UPC from COST_TAB group by COST_TAB.UPC having (Count(COST_TAB.UPC) >1) and COST_TAB.UPC = 'F01'
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want all the fields in the rows of duplicates (otherwise, a simple aggregation query gets you the `F01` values).  I would use window functions for this:

```
select ct.*
from (select ct.*, count(*) over (partition by f01) as cnt
      from cost_tab ct
     ) ct
where cnt > 1;
```

Comment: with all due respect... this actual doesn't work. I updated it for ya... ;) +1

Comment: @samyi . . . Your modifications were incorrect.  If you don't understand something, ask.

Comment: Please take a look at your original answer. It is not the same as the one you updated to. The original answer, in fact, is incorrect. I would argue that your "new" answer, while it works, is still poorly written (ambiguous table alias). If you want to know why it's incorrect, please ask. ;)

Comment: @samyi . . . I added the `ct` alias.  You changed other things in the query.