# SQL WHERE Temporary Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this MSSQL Query which works

```
SELECT c.CategoryName + ' (' + cast(count(ic.CategoryId) as varchar(255)) + ')' AS
 CategoryName, count(ic.CategoryId) AS NumPhotos,
  c.Slug, c.ParentCategoryId, c.Id
FROM Categories
 c LEFT JOIN
 ItemCategories ic
 on ic.CategoryId = c.Id
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, c.slug, c.ParentCategoryId, c.id
ORDER BY ParentCategoryId DESC
```

And I want to return only rows, WHERE NumPhotos>0 but temporary columns are not allowed on SQL WHERE clause

Comment: `HAVING count(ic.CategoryId) > 0`   -- NumPhotos is just an aliased name for that count.

Comment: Add `HAVING count(ic.CategoryId) > 0`  before the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query for finding records where count > 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151401/sql-query-for-finding-records-where-count-1)

Comment: If I add HAVING count... then I get this error Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'GROUP'.

Comment: If I add it after ORDER BY then it work, please add it as a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `having` clause is the canonical solution to your problem.  However, I suspect that an `inner join` would also be appropriate:

```
SELECT c.CategoryName + ' (' + cast(count(ic.CategoryId) as varchar(255)) + ')' AS CategoryName,
       count(ic.CategoryId) AS NumPhotos,
       c.Slug, c.ParentCategoryId, c.Id
FROM Categories c INNER JOIN
     ItemCategories ic
     on ic.CategoryId = c.Id
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, c.slug, c.ParentCategoryId, c.id
ORDER BY ParentCategoryId DESC;
```

Without sample data, it is hard to be sure, but I'm pretty sure this does the same thing.

The advantage of an `inner join` is that it might be more efficient, because less (maybe only slightly less) data would be processed and the optimizer has more opportunities to pick the best `join` algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Existing comments have given adequate answers, but here is another solution, using a "virtual table":

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
SELECT c.CategoryName + ' (' + cast(count(ic.CategoryId) as varchar(255)) + ')' AS
 CategoryName, count(ic.CategoryId) AS NumPhotos,
  c.Slug, c.ParentCategoryId, c.Id
FROM Categories
 c LEFT JOIN
 ItemCategories ic
 on ic.CategoryId = c.Id
GROUP BY c.CategoryName, c.slug, c.ParentCategoryId, c.id
) 
WHERE NumPhotos>0
ORDER BY ParentCategoryId DESC
```

Comment: It seems that it also works with HAVING count... after the ORDER BY, and it's much faster.

Comment: running your query gives me this error: Msg 1033, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, subqueries, and common table expressions, unless TOP, OFFSET or FOR XML is also specified.