# Group by on a column with duplicates (string values)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to create a MS SQL Query on the table below.

Consider I have following single table:

[image]

I want to get the following result by grouping on column1:

[image]

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Any efforts for this result?

Comment: Why `column2` and `column3` are `N/A`?

Comment: @Ullas Because it doesn't make sense, I don't need that information. And also, it's impossible to show these on one row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query for finding records where count > 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151401/sql-query-for-finding-records-where-count-1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `COUNT` with `GROUP BY`.

**Query**

```
SELECT column1, 'N/A' as column2, 'N/A' as column3,
COUNT(column1) AS column4_amount
FROM your_table_name
GROUP BY column1;
```

Comment: And can I also edit this query so that it only shows the result with 2 or more duplicates? If it only occurs once, then I don't want to show it.

Comment: @Ozkan use `HAVING count(1) > 1`, Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column1, 'N/A' as column2, 'N/A' as column3, COUNT(1) AS column4_amount
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column1
```

if you don't need column2 and column3 then try below:

```
SELECT column1, COUNT(1) AS column4_amount
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column1
```

Update:
As you want results which has **more than one occurrence**, try this:

```
SELECT column1, 'N/A' as column2, 'N/A' as column3, COUNT(1) AS column4_amount
FROM table_name
GROUP BY column1
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use  `GROUP BY` with *column1* as `GROUP BY` helps you group all the items with the same name.

To count total items under a group of items, from the table with the same name, use the `COUNT` aggregate function. Now you need to check that each item exists more than once. Use the `HAVING` clause which takes all the groups that have more than two items.

```
SELECT column1, 'N/A' as column2, 'N/A' as column3, COUNT(1) AS column4_amount
FROM your_table_name
       GROUP BY column1
       HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

Comment: Although this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ it answers
the question would significantly improve its long-term
value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.