# SQL Query which returns records which appear X times in table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have an SQL table responsible for storing instances of user's flagging content. This is my table:

```
Flagged Content

1. instance_id
2. content_id
3. user_id`
```

Now I want to execute a query which returns all the `content_id` which appear at least `3` times within the `flagged content` table. However, I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: no attempt shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query for finding records where count > 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151401/sql-query-for-finding-records-where-count-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the count using `group by`:

```
select content_id
from flagged_content fc 
group by content_id
having count(*) >= 3;
```

If you want the original records, then use a `join`:

```
select fc.*
from flagged_content fc join
     (select content_id
      from flagged_content fc 
      group by content_id
      having count(*) >= 3
     ) c
     on fc.content_id = c.content_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT content_id
FROM flagged_content
GROUP BY content_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT content_id
FROM flagged_content
GROUP BY content_id
HAVING count(instance_id) > 3;
```

or replace instance_id with the primary key/not null column. (Not sure whether count(*) works for all RDBMS)