# Prevent a computed column from appearing in the result set

Tags: mysql

Assuming the following query:

```
SELECT meta_value as xyz, COUNT(*) AS count
  FROM wp_postmeta
  WHERE meta_key = "xyz" AND meta_value != ""
  GROUP BY meta_value
  HAVING count > 1
```

The query works fine, but I don't need the `count` column in my results.  How can the `count` column be excluded?

I know I can use a subquery (as shown below), but I'd like to know if there's a better way.

```
SELECT xyz FROM (
  SELECT meta_value as xyz, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE meta_key = "xyz" AND meta_value != ""
    GROUP BY meta_value
    HAVING count > 1
) AS t
```

Comment: `HAVING count > 1` is using the alias count from the select... So you could substitute `count(*)` instead of the alias in the HAVING clause and eliminate count(*) and the alias from the select.  Thus it becomes something like `SELECT meta_value as xyz... HAVING count(*) > 1`

Comment: The first answer in this question should solve your problem: [stackoverflow.com/questions/7151401/...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151401/sql-query-for-finding-records-where-count-1). Move the `COUNT(*)` to your `HAVING` clause...

Comment: @xQbert add it as an answer

Comment: @xQbert - It works!  Thank you!  If you'd like to add an answer, I'll accept it.  If it's better to mark this as a duplicate or delete it, that's cool with me, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HAVING count > 1` is using the alias count from the select... So you could substitute `count(*)` instead of the alias (count) in the HAVING clause and eliminate count(*) and the alias from the select. Thus it becomes something like

```
SELECT meta_value as xyz
... 
HAVING count(*) > 1
```

Order of operations matter here.  Having works after the select thus it could use the alias in the select or it can run the count at time of execution.  Same thing with order by.  But a group by could never use an select alias within the same statement.